# How to use Applescript to get VLC to open a mms stream

Tags: applescript, vlc

I tried

```
tell application "VLC" to open mms://mms_address
```

But it's not working. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `OpenURL`:

```
tell application "VLC"
    OpenURL "mms://mms_address"
end tell
```